# How to Run UI Test by TFS2015?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015

I upgraded my TFS-2013 to TFS-2015 and then define new build definition with 3 steps

1. MSBuild
2. Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment
3. Visual Studio Test 
   using test agent

I selected test group for the second step and add username and password 
for the third step. I selected the test group and test drop folder which contains test DLLs and I added the DLL file name which contains coded UI test method to test assembly.

when I tried to deploy test agent I found this log :

> [debug]Calling Invoke-DeployTestAgent DistributedTests: Starting to deploy and configure test agent on test machines. DistributedTests:
>   Inputs provided are: DistributedTests: Machines: TestPC3
>   DistributedTests: Username: user123 DistributedTests: Machine Group
>   name: testui DistributedTests: Run as process: True DistributedTests:
>   Login Automatically: True DistributedTests: Disable Screen saver: True
>   DistributedTests: Agent location:
>   \user-pc\drop_Location\vstf_testagent.exe DistributedTests: Update
>   test agent: True DistributedTests: Run test agent as DataCollection
>   only : False DistributedTests: Path to script that installs test agent
>   on remote machine:
>   G:\agentui\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.2\TestAgentInstall.ps1
>   DistributedTests: Path to script that configures test agent on remote
>   machine:
>   G:\agentui\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.2\TestAgentConfiguration.ps1
>   DistributedTests: Path to script that checks if test agent is
>   installed on remote machine:
>   G:\agentui\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.2\CheckTestAgentInstallation.ps1
>   DistributedTests: Creating DTL client  DistributedTests: Getting
>   Machine Group with name = testui project = TestBuildLifeCycle
>   DistributedTests: Got Machine Group with name = testui project =
>   TestBuildLifeCycle DistributedTests: Cleaning up tags from machines
>   DistributedTests: Removing tag 'Microsoft-AgentsForVS' on machine
>   'TestPC3' DistributedTests: Getting list of machines from machinename
>   completed DistributedTests: Updating environment resources with
>   TestAgent tag DistributedTests: Test Agent is being copied to:
>   C:\Users\userFolder\AppData\Local\Temp\2c15a489-7765-4a41-b78e-09197ee5d2c8\vstf_testagent.exe
>   DistributedTests: Preparing for copying files from
>   C:\Users\userFolder\AppData\Local\Temp\2c15a489-7765-4a41-b78e-09197ee5d2c8\vstf_testagent.exe
>   to $env:SystemDrive\TestAgent  DistributedTests: Setting up Copy task
>   for Agent : TestPC3  DistributedTests: Total machines where task
>   CopyFilesToTestAgent needs to be run : 1 DistributedTests: Task
>   'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine 'TestPC3' is being run
>   DistributedTests: Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine 'TestPC3'
>   completed. DistributedTests: Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' for machine
>   TestPC3's Status : Failed DistributedTests: Task
>   'CopyFilesToTestAgent' for machine TestPC3's Log :
>   System.AggregateException: Failed to create working directory on the
>   machine. Consult the logs below for details of the error.  An object
>   at the specified path C:\Users\J3CA7~1.JSH does not exist.

I used administrator's credentials and solved this issue by install agent manual but need to make it able to edit the agent 
I've noticed that the process tries to copy test agent to temp folder in appData and then try to copy this agent to c:\testAgent but it failes

Comment: can you shown me the detailed build log file on the Diagnostics page?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running coded UI tests, you must configure your build agent to **run interactively**. Before you try to use your build process to run tests, make sure they can be run on the build server that you plan to use.

There are some things you should pay attention to:

**Prepare**

1. Make sure your solution and your test files are checked into version control.
2. Microsoft Visual Studio is required to be installed on the build server for the following scenario: To run unit tests, or coded UI tests, you must install **Visual Studio Professional or later**.
3. Many tests and test operations (including Code UI test) require that you install on your build agent **the same version of Visual Studio** that your team uses on its dev machines.

**To run your build server in interactive mode**

1. Identify the user account that will act as the build service account. The build service account must:

   - Be a member of the Windows Administrators group on the build server.
   - Be a member of the Build Service Accounts group on your team project collection.
   - Have Change and Read privileges on the drop folder, if any, that you plan to specify in your build definition.
2. On the Build Service Properties dialog box, choose `Stop the service`.
3. Under Run the Service as, choose `Change`, and then specify the credentials of the build service account.
4. Select `Run the Service interactively`.
5. Choose `Start`, and then choose `OK`.
6. Leave the build service account logged on to the build server.

For more details and screenshots: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712(v=vs.120).aspx#interactive

Comment: Thank you for you reply but this screenshot is related to tfs 2013, in tfs 2015 i used interactive build agent and select test machine it should download test agent form website but it failed in the log i found this exception  "DistributedTests: Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' for machine TestPC3.idscan.com's Error : System.AggregateException: Failed to create working directory on the machine. Consult the logs below for details of the error" I'm not able to detect where is the issue

Comment: @Tama, can you shown me the detailed build log file on the Diagnostics page?

Comment: @Vicky - MSFT I added the log to my question please check the Update

Answer (score 0):

On step 2 (deploying test agent) you will need to enable the "Interactive" option.

For more detail: https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DeployVisualStudioTestAgent/README.md

Comment: I checked interactive check box but when i try to deploy test agent i got this exception "DistributedTests: Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' for machine TestPC3.idscan.com's Error : System.AggregateException: Failed to create working directory on the machine. Consult the logs below for details of the error" I'm not able to detect where is the issue
An object at the specified path C:\Users\J3CA7~1.KAH does not exist.
+At line:5 char:17

Comment: I hope that you enable WinRM to this computer.

Comment: And this path looks very strange, as though there FAT32 file system.
I'm not sure that is possible to execute UI tests in that environment.
Anyway, check the permissions of the user who carried out the testagent. It must be an local administrator.